# Asp.net Core MVC Dynamically add Select List via JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, selectlistitem

I am trying to provide a view where people will be able to create a list of categories and sub categories. Therefore I need to allow users to dynamically add Rows.
Each Row will allow user to add a category and then if they wish a Sub Category. For the first row I am able to use **asp-items** attributes to bind to a **SelectList** in my **ViewBag**, however when I add a new row via JS I cannot do it, I have tried 2 methods JS (both shown in the code):

- 1 - Storing the SelectList in a variable and looping through it
- 2 - Setting the asp-items to the SelectList

Does anyone know how I can populate my newly added rows? Also how would I bind the enetred in data to my Model; would it have to be done in the controller?

The code is as follows:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var categories = "@ViewBag.Categories";
        var catOptions = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < categories; i++) {
            catOptions = catOptions + '<option value="' + categories[i].CategoryId + '">' + categories[i].Name + '</option>'
        }

        $(document).on("click", "#btnAddCat", function () {
            var newCat =''+
                '<tr class="categorieRows">' +
                    '<td colspan="2">' +
                '<select>' +
                    catOptions +
                '</select>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                        '<button type="button" id="btnAddSubCat" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add Sub Category</button>' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $('#categoryTable').append(newCat);
        });

        $(document).on("click", "#btnAddSubCat", function () {
            var newSubCat = '' +
                '<tr class="categorieRows">' +
                    '<td></td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                        '<select asp-items="ViewBag.SubCategories"></select>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td></td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $('#categoryTable').append(newSubCat);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
@model IEnumerable<Categories>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Surveys</h4>
<hr />
<table class="table table-striped" id="categoryTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Category
            </th>
            <th>
                Sub Categories
            </th>
            <th>
                <button type="button" id="btnAddCat" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add Category</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="categorieRows">
            <td colspan="2">
                <select asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="btnAddSubCat" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add Sub Category</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its all a function of your setup for the backend, how are you structuring the database to handle cat/subcat?

Comment: its a SQL Server backend which i have connected using Context class. both classes are very small: Categories(CategoryID, Name), SubCategory(SubCategoryID, CategoryID, Name)

Comment: Some of the things you have indicated would lead me to believe you are relatively new to mvc. Most of the stuff you have indicated is Client Side except for a call to an WebAPI  to post the data to..

To be honest this would be something along the line of angular/vuejs to handle the dynamic nature of the interface.  With a axiom or ajax call to push the data into the database.  I myself wouldn't use 2 table to do it either, saving a little overhead.  Using a js framework for the interface is doable in asp.net core mvc.

Comment: What are you setting to `ViewBag.Categories` ?

Comment: Its a SelectList created in the controller which retrieves the Categories from the DB.

Comment: @mvermef yes fairly new to MVC, angular is a good call thanks. I did end up using Ajax calls to retrieve Categories & Sub Category data and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Ajax calls to retrieve Categories data:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("change", "#selectCategroy", function () {
            var subCat = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: "ReturnJsonSubCategories/?categoryId=" + $(subCat).val(),
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: JSON,
                success: function (result) {
                    var categories = "";
                    $(result).each(function () {
                        categories = categories + '<option value="' + this.subCategoryId + '">' + this.name + '</option>'
                    });

                    var subCateList = $("#selectSubCategroy");
                    subCateList.empty();
                    subCateList.append(categories);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    return "Error";
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

With the server side code looking like:

```
public JsonResult ReturnJsonSubCategories(int categoryId)
    {
        var jsonData = _context.SubCategories.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId).ToList();
        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar with the last answer but a bit shorter

```
$(function () {
    $('#CategoryId').change(function () {
        $('#SubCategoryId').empty();
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "api/CategoryApi/ListSubCategories";
        $.getJSON(url, { categoryId: $('#CategoryId').val() })
            .done(function (data) {
                var subcategories = "";
                $(data).each(function () {
                    subcategories += '<option value="' + this.CategoryId + '">' + this.Title + '</option>'
                });
                $('#SubCategoryId').append(subcategories);
        })
    });
});
```

and on server side

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ListSubCategories")]
    public IActionResult ListSubCategories(int categoryId)
    {
        var subCategories = _categorySvc.ListSubCategories(categoryId);
        return Ok(subCategories);
    }
```