# How to add textbox [Input field] inside drop down for inserting more field which is not merge with dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]How do add a textbox [Input field] inside the drop-down for inserting more fields which is not merging with the dropdown using the [image]Razor page?

```
Hello everyone,
Anyone can help me to solve this issue?
I have one dropdown like city and for some of the cities' names I have added with dropdown, I want to add one text box inside the dropdown, using this text box, the user can add a city name that does not exist inside 
dropdown.
I have added below code
```

the javascript library and select2()  method but this method is used for searchable textbox, I want to add an input field.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/py8t5.png
```

```
<div class="row mb-3">
            <label asp-for="user.Address" class="control-label"></label>

            <select id="ddlAddress" asp-for="user.Address" class="form-control">
                <option selected disabled>Select Address</option>              
                <option>Casario</option>
                <option>Casabella</option>
                <option>Lodha heaven</option>              
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="user.Address" class="text-danger"></span>            
        </div>

@section scripts{
    @{
                        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"></partial>
    }

    <link  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#ddlDiseases").select2();
           
            $("#ddlAddress").attributesSelect2(); 

                                          
            
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: If you want to add options dynamically, you can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875018/asp-net-core-mvc-dynamically-add-select-list-via-js)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element :

```html
<label for="ddlAddress">Address :</label>
<input list="adress-list" id="ddlAddress" name="address" />
<datalist id="adress-list">
    <option value="Casario">
    <option value="Casabella">
    <option value="Lodha heaven">
</datalist>
```

If you use Bootstrap 5, datalists are part of the [custom form controls](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists).

Comment: This code works as the search box, I don't want to add a search box, I want to add a textbox and when I add value inside text instead of a dropdown, then the textbox's value should be inserted inside the database